# Physically view pixel location in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, shapes

I am trying to draw a bunch of random shapes and lines in a JFrame. Is there any way to see where the locations of x and y are without randomly inserting a number and guessing then adjusting accordingly after running the program? It gets really tedious trying to position everything perfectly...especially with the amount that I am drawing. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know. The only thing I've thought of is using a mouse pointer location but if there is anything easier please let me know. Thank you!!

Comment: You could use `Robot`, but that's expensive and gets messy quick.  A better solution might be to use a `BufferedImage` to render your content to and simply paint to the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the point of the pixel ahead of time, you could draw the point (in this case, an X marks the spot) in the paint method, in a class that extends JFrame.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    int x = 50;
    int y = 50;

    super.paint(g);
    g.drawLine(x-2, y-2, x+2, y+2); 
    g.drawLine(x-2, y+2, x+2, y-2);
}
```

Modify the 2 to change the length/size of the X.

Comment: That would work too. I'm just trying to figure out a way to visibly see it without having to estimate how much I need to change a certain point. It would sure be nice to use a gui builder and just add them in!